# CSS "realistic" shadows (light source)

Tags: jquery, effects, css, light

Have a look at the picture below:

[image: skyscrapers]

The blue boxes are divs. Now what I am trying to do is to implement a sort of 2.5D functionality:

I would like the grey shadows to be somewhat 3D-ish. At first I was thinking to assign to the box-shadow value the "Y" axis like this:

```
"box-shadow: -5px -5px 10px" + value.tallness +  "#888"
```

but the result is the above image.

Any idea on how to make the shadow on one side only, like there was a light source from somewhere?

EXTRA - what about a *moving* "light source"?

Comment: I am working on an example on jsfiddle. Trying to make the moving light source :D

Comment: If you don't mind using a plugin realshadows.js is really good. http://jsfiddle.net/AA69G/

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There you go: http://jsfiddle.net/KaCDN/15/

Drag light source to affect shadows.

Taller blocks:

- have larger top,left border
- drop shadow further
- they're shadow is blurier

Comment: Updated: taller blocks have a lighter color.

Comment: Update2: Taller blocks drop shadow further than shorter blocks.

Comment: Hmm, one problem is that the shadow from one div appears on top of another div. Don't know if it's possible to make the shadows be bottom-most, as long as they're created using box-shadow.

Comment: Update: Distance between light source and block affects shadow's size.

Comment: that code seems so complicated! a great example by the way! I really got no clue where to start modifying it, aha. where do i change shadow color (they seem a bit too white-ish) and "definition"? so that the shadow border is less blurry?

Comment: I'll add comments to the code to make it easier to understand.

Comment: There you go, added some comments.

Answer (score 4):

How to move the shadow a little simpler:

```
$(document).on('mousemove', function(e) {
    var elm = $("#test"),
        x = ~Math.round((e.pageX - elm[0].offsetLeft - 150) / 30),
        y = ~Math.round((e.pageY - elm[0].offsetTop - 150) / 30),
        z = 10+Math.abs(x)+Math.abs(y),
        cssVal = x+'px '+y+'px '+z+'px 10px #525252';

    elm.css({'-webkit-box-shadow' : cssVal, 'box-shadow' : cssVal });
});
```

​[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/2f5kw/3/)

Comment: +1 like it! Nice one - I'd also add: if light source is far away: make the shadow more 'dispersive' ;)

Comment: @Roko - Sure, why not! Edited my answer?

Answer (score 1):

A more up-to-date answer would be to use a library like Shine.js (http://bigspaceship.github.io/shine.js/) which would handle this exact problem for you.