# What is wrong with this JSON file?

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I put it in a parser and all it gives me is "expecting string on line 19". I have no idea what that means.

```
{
    "name": "Rajeev",
    "children": [
        {
            "name": "Joe",
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "Kevin",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "George"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "John",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "Barb",

                        }{
                            "name": "Michael",

                        }{
                            "name": "Charles"
                        }
                    ]{
                        "name": "Ravinder"
                    ]
                },
```

Comment: It's just not valid JSON. You need to learn the rules of JSON so that you can understand what's valid and what isn't.

Comment: To check and validate your json data [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com/) is your friend.

Answer (score 1):

Your commas are in the wrong place, e.g.

```
"children": [
                    {
                        "name": "Barb"

                    },{
                        "name": "Michael"

                    },{
                        "name": "Charles"
                    }
                ]
```

Comment: Good point, Stephen. BTW, please undelete your answer in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22360919/javascript-use-var-value-as-name-for-new-var) -- I wanted to upvote and leave a comment. It wasn't the winning solution, but it did work and gave me some good ideas. (In fact, it almost was what I ended up staying with.) Worth keeping.

Answer (score 1):

The left one is the right one. see for yourself. you had many extra `,` and unclosed `{` and `[`

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yKNN.jpg
[image]

Comment: @downvoter. tnx. I think it's the best answer to show and teach. IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the first answer, I saw a missing comma and automatically assumed that was it, but there were many other errors in there. I think this is what you're trying to do

```
[
        {
            "name": "Rajeev",
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "Joe",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "Kevin",
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "name": "George"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "John",
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "name": "Barb"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "Michael"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "Charles"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Ravinder"
        }
    ]
```

Comment: While there are missing commas (plural!), they aren't the cause of the error the question is asking about.

Comment: @Quentin: I think he's asking generally what's wrong with the JSON file, as suggested by the title.

Answer (score 0):

You have a property / value:

```
     "name": "Barb",
```

… *with a trailing comma* so the next thing must be another property / value (the string mentioned in the error message is the property name).

However you have:

```
}{
```

Either remove the comma or add more details about Barb.

Then you will need to put a comma *between* the two objects:

```
}, {
```

It seems likely that you intended to place the comma causing teh error between the two objects, so you can just move them.

(You have similar errors throughout the rest of the file)